# PHP/MySQL Cannot INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I'm facing a quite strange problem, with an error I've never saw before.

This is my code:

```
<?php
funcion addPref($nome, $uid, $valore){
   $SQL = "INSERT INTO preferenze_utenti (idPreferenza, idUtente, value) 
   VALUES ((SELECT id FROM preferenze WHERE nome = ?), ?, ?)";
   $stmt = $GLOBALS["db"]->prepare($SQL);
   $stmt->bind_param('sis', $nome, $uid, $valore);
   return $stmt->execute() ? true : false;
}
?>
```

I'm using the function like this:

```
addPref("css_animations", 530, "true");
```

Mind that `"true"` is a string, because this table accept multiple types of data into it, so I'm just using it like this.

The problem is that actually the function returns always true, and I get no new db record for it.
I've tried running the query directly in PHPMyAdmin and works perfectly.
I've noticed that i got this warning from MySQL:

> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'css_animations '

Where am I going wrong?

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `preferenze_utenti` (
  `idPreferenza` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `idUtente` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `preferenze` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `nome` char(64) NOT NULL,
  `def` varchar(128) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Valore default'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Show us your structure of you table pls.

Comment: whats the table definition of preferenze_utenti?

Comment: What type is column `nome` in `preferenze`?

Comment: @u_mulder is a string.

Comment: I've added sql exports of the two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `VALUES` when you use `SELECT` as on here:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO preferenze_utenti (idPreferenza, idUtente, value)
        VALUES ((SELECT id FROM preferenze WHERE nome = ?), ?, ?)";
```

Change it to:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO preferenze_utenti (idPreferenza, idUtente, value)
       ((SELECT id FROM preferenze WHERE nome = ?), ?, ?)";
```

Comment: It worked! I've just rewrote the code using this query and actually worked.
What's the difference between using VALUES or not?

Comment: @DarioEmerson it is a MySQL syntax standard that we must never use `VALUES` if the data to insert needs to be fetched by a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Didn't know that, always used and never had problems with.
Thanks for the help!